# Trouble Configuring Azure Event Grid Topic to Event Hub Event Forwarding

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

I aim to transmit Events from an Azure Event Grid Topic to an Event Hub. The desired setup involves disabling public network access while allowing an exception for trusted Microsoft services through an Event Subscription.

I followed this configuration approach:

[image: Event Hub Configuration: Public Access - Disabled, Exception for Trusted Microsoft Services - Enabled]

Additionally, I configured the Event Subscription to utilize the Managed Identity of the Topic. I granted the Data Sender permission with the Event Hub Namespace as the designated scope according to [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/private-link-service?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_EventHub#trusted-microsoft-services).

Despite these steps, the events continue to encounter failures in being published through the Event Grid Topic. I'm seeking advice on potential misconfigurations or any recommendations you might have to assist me in achieving my objective.

Answer (score 0):

I also had tried in the same way but encountering the failures. Then I had made some changes in the below please check.

[image]

- Azure Private Link allows you to access Azure services, including Event Hubs, over a private network connection rather than the public internet. This can help enhance security and control over your data transmission.

Create a Private Endpoint for your Event Hub and associate it with a virtual network.

- Event Grid Topic, Event Hub, and the virtual network containing the Private Endpoints are in the same Azure region.
- Test the event transmission to verify that it works correctly over the private network connection. Generate events in the Event Grid Topic and confirm that they are delivered to the Event Hub.

Now, Iam able to forward the events to the Event Hub without encountering any failures.

[image]

Azure Private Link is prioritizing security and data control. It helps you build a more secure and compliant data architecture within the Azure ecosystem.